# Capturing Value From Array In Load Runner

Tags: c, loadrunner, vugen

I am adding multiple product to an account and saving. In save response i am getting my productID in an array
e.g. "productID" :[1234,3456,2578]

But in subsequent request i need to send these Id's individually not in array. How can i capture this value using correlation.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please, post the code you are currently using (just the minimum part required to understand the issue) and ecplain better what are you trying to do, as it is not clear at all...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.